# How to check a if a string contains a letter in c?

Tags: c, char, c-strings, strchr

I have to check if a character(string) contains a scanned letter.

```
char password[15]="STACKOVERFLOW";
char check;
printf("Type in a letter to check if it is in the password/n");
scanf("%c", check);
```

Now I want to check if the check is in the password and print true or false.

Comment: [strchr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/) is what you are looking for, in this case `if (strchr(password, c)) printf("%c is in password\n", c);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a string contains a certain character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146750/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-certain-character)

Comment: Can I also use strchr to check if there is a number in a string?

Comment: @JuhászKoppány do you mean a digit? in this case [strspn](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strspn/) is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

For starters use

```
scanf(" %c", check);
       ^^^^
```

instead of

```
scanf("%c", check);
```

to skip white space characters from the input stream.

To check whether a character is present in a string use the standard function `strchr` declared in the header `<string.h>`. For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...


if ( strchr( password, check ) == NULL ) // if ( !strchr( password, check ) )
{
    puts( "The character is absent" );
}
```

Or

```
if ( strchr( password, check ) ) 
{
    puts( "Bingo! The character is present" );
}
```